# Ceiling fan light periodically flickering

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I had brand new electricity installed in an addition and the ceiling fan light flickers periodically. We replaced the unit thinking it was the unit but it has continued to happen. First it was a light bulb unit and now it is an integrated LED unit so it is not a bulb issue. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of switch?

Answer (score 1):

LEDs are NOTORIOUSLY sensitive to any variation in voltage and react INSTANTLY, unlike incandescent bulbs. Anything with a high starting current (clothes washer, dryer, fridge, freezer, A/C unit) could cause a short term voltage dip which could cause the flicker.   Try to associate the flicker with other electrical usage to give you some peace of mind.  The flicker would be worse if the high starting current device (like a window A/C unit is on the same circuit). You may want to have your mains inspected for damage, just to be safe. It's not likely a problem, just annoying, but having your main panel checked is a good idea.   Also if the feed from the power company is sketchy that could also cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks George. I think the issue is going to run a bit deeper actually. We ran all of the electircal on the addition to one breaker (just one bedroom and a hallway so not a ton of load) and the breaker just tripped when a table saw was running on it. I suppose we could be having more electircal issues but the ceiling fan is the only thing that has been running thus far in the new build.

Comment: Thanks for the resp.   Was it a GFCI breaker?What amperage? I hate to say it, but just one circuit to the new area of your house seems pretty thin.  Even a table top table saw can draw quite a lot of power.  Is the table saw a permanent installation or just for construction? If permanent, you need more power (capt'n, I'm given' you all she's got).